# How can I make validation attribute MVC for two properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter name")]
    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Remote("ValidateProductName", "Products", ErrorMessage = "Product with this name already exist")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter price")]
    [Range(0.1, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Price must be greater than 0")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter quantity")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    //[Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The value must be greater than 0")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    //[DateRange("01/01/2050")]
    [CurrentDate(ErrorMessage = "You enter invalid data")]
    public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter if is in promotion")]
    public bool InPromotion { get; set; }
}
```

I want to check if quantity multiple price is greater than 100 000,and if is greater to write error message.I need to use attribute.Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a custom attribute for your logic.

```
public class ValidatePriceAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{
    private double maxVal = 0.0;
    public ValidatePriceAttribute(double maxVal)
    {
       this.maxVal = maxVal;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext ctx)
    {
        var obj = ctx.ObjectInstance as Product;

        if (obj != null) {
              if( obj.Price * obj.Quantity > this.maxVal){
                     return new ValidationResult("error message goes here");
              }
        } 

       return null;
    }
}
```

Use like

```
[ValidatePrice(100000.0)]
public double Price {get;set;}
```

The above code is sample only, it needs a lot of improvement to make it more flexible and generic and I leave that exercise to you :)